How to find Rth for the given circuit?
I know how to proceed with the question after Rth is found but I am not able to calculate equivalent resistance for the given circuit. I am not able to resolve the 3 ohm and 4 ohm resistance.


Why do you think you need to 'resolve' the 3 and 4 ohm resistors? In series, they are simply equivalent to a 7 ohm resistor.

Clues are to replace the 10V 5 ohm thevenin                with  2Amp 5 ohm norton.Then you get 8 Amp norton with your paralell combo .Now you thevanin it to get one voltage source and you know the   total      source resistance     so your soln is when  source resistance equals RL


I am not able to resolve the 3 ohm and 4 ohm resistance.

It's simply recognizing that to solve the problem you can regard the 3 Ω and 4 Ω resistors as being in series like this: -


Thanks for explaining! Can you please also clarify how to look at the circuit and determine 3 and 4 ohm are in series?

The 3 ohm, the load and the 4 ohm resistors all share exactly the same current at all times therefore they are in series @AaryanMagnani and, you can rearrange them as you wish without altering that fact.

Thanks for the clarification @Andy aka!!

@AaryanMagnani if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

The order of series connected elements (so long as nothing else is connected at their junctions) doesn't change the current through them, or the voltages across each element:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
From the perspective of RL, those three arrangements make no difference to its own current and voltage, so the whole thing can be redrawn like this:

simulate this circuit
This won't change the voltage across RL, or the current through it, but in this form it's clear you can replace R1 and R2 with a single 7Ω resistance, thus "resolving" your 3Ω and 4Ω dilemma.

Thank you for clarifying! Can you please explain again how they are in series by looking at the circuit? We have been told to remove RL and just make it an open ended circuit and then calculate RTH so its difficult to see how the 3 and 4 ohm are in series..?

When you say "open", all that means is $R_L=\infty \Omega$, but the 3Ω, ∞Ω and 4Ω are still in series. It doesn't matter whether $R_L=\infty \Omega$ or $R_L=0\Omega$, the 3Ω, $R_L$ and  4Ω resistors are in series.

Thanks for explaining @Simon Fitch!!
